# .NET App runing but not displayed in browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm developing a web MVC app using .NET Framework 4.7

Since two days, I can't access to my app in the browser. It runs in Visual Studio 2019 but not in the browser. I have a 404. I think the problem is from my computer because my mates can run my app on their own computer. Maybe it's a problem with IIS but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe, you want to use one Port twice?

Comment: Maybe it's my error but how to disable this ?

Comment: Is it IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: did you host the application in iis? or just running from the visual studio? what is the sub status code?

Comment: It’s IIs express and it’s jun running from VS